# GoogleSignIn with Flutter on IOS - build fails

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, google-signin

The build fails for IOS when I use **googlesignin plugin** with flutter. It works fine for android. Including the error below. I have already tried flutter clean and also tried to start with a fresh project.

````
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           304.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2020-05-25 09:28:41.547 xcodebuild[21636:235481]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 00008030-001345E602B8802E was NULL
    2020-05-25 09:28:41.613 xcodebuild[21636:235481]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 00008030-001345E602B8802E was NULL
    2020-05-25 09:28:42.304 xcodebuild[21636:235481]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 00008006-000B25610CEB002E was NULL
    2020-05-25 09:28:42.309 xcodebuild[21636:235451]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 00008006-000B25610CEB002E was NULL
    2020-05-25 09:28:42.442 xcodebuild[21636:235398] [MT] DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 00008006-000B25610CEB002E was NULL
    2020-05-25 09:28:42.448 xcodebuild[21636:235398] [MT] DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 00008006-000B25610CEB002E was NULL
    2020-05-25 09:28:42.453 xcodebuild[21636:235398] [MT] DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 00008006-000B25610CEB002E was NULL
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2KeychainCompatibility", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthStateMigration_425a588fcd149b383bb30d0e6a3b4322.o)
      "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization", referenced from:
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationWithEMMSupport in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_2dc0a81d98f461bd0c0b7c8749d3689a.o)
         (maybe you meant: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationEMMChainedDelegate, _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationWithEMMSupport )
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMKeychain", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthStateMigration_425a588fcd149b383bb30d0e6a3b4322.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization", referenced from:
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationWithEMMSupport in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_2dc0a81d98f461bd0c0b7c8749d3689a.o)
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_2dc0a81d98f461bd0c0b7c8749d3689a.o)
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_2f842adf59cff94dba6bfcb1043c2758.o)
          objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthStateMigration_425a588fcd149b383bb30d0e6a3b4322.o)
         (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationWithEMMSupport, _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationEMMChainedDelegate )
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on... iPhone.```
````

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow all the instructions on the [Start integrating Google Sign In into your iOS App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating).

This includes:

1. Adding the `GoogleSignIn` pod
2. Adding a URL scheme to your project
3. Possibly configure the `GIDSignIn` shared instance following the instructions on the next page of the link.

Comment: I believe this is all done by flutter automatically at the time of compilation. I should not have to manually add pod and other steps. I already added the URL scheme.

Comment: @saanvib It's possible that its supposed to be done by flutter automatically. However, these were steps that I had to do to successfully build for iOS when using Google Sign In.

Comment: @saanvib Have you actually tried what I suggested? Those steps were necessary for me to get it working in my own project.

Comment: @saanvib Did you configure the `GIDSignIn` shared instance as well?